# Parallel execution with in @test annotation

Tags: java, selenium, testng

i have testNG test which will return list of url to test against and it executes one by one i want atleast 2 urls to run at the same time.. what would be the best way to do this ?

```
@Test
public static void test1() throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = Configuration.getConfiguration();

    List<String> urls = conf.getListOfUrls(); // returns list of urls to test against

    setup(); //has capabilities for IE browser

    for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {

        WebDriver.get(urls.get(z));

        //do stuff

        }
```

Comment: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests use parallel tests in conjunction with splitting your list in half

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211726/testng-parallel-execution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use DataProvider in TestNG to get it. Lets say in Data Provider pass multiple datasets i.e. urls contains in List urls = conf.getListOfUrls();

Below is the simple example:

```
  @Test(dataProvider="testdata")
public void simpleTest(String url) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
}

@DataProvider(name="testdata", parallel=true)
public Object[][] data(){
    return new Object[][] {
        {"http://www.google.com"},
        {"http://www.seleniumhq.org"}
    };
```

Comment: thanks @murali. it is launching 2 browsers now, but the problem now is that there are actions which should be performed after opening of browsers, which is only being performed on one of the browser which started. how do i get the actions to run on all the browser instances which opens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544135/parllel-execution-with-in-test-annotations  please help!

Comment: @Noob try once without parallel = true in data provision, if it works fine then we need to look further. i will look 2row

Answer (score 0):

You can use parallel execution like below code :

```
package com.demo.core;


import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class PlayField {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver getChromeDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                           "D:\\ECLIPSE-WORKSPACE\\playground\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver-2.35.exe");

        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        driver = getChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        driver.navigate().to("Url1");
        // do anything
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        driver.navigate().to("Url2");
        //do anything
    }

}
```

and in testng.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="First suite" verbose="8" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Default test1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.demo.core.PlayField">
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

and then run this xml using surefire plugin or directly.
It will open two browsers at the same time.
Hope this helps you.