# Parllel execution with in @Test annotations

Tags: selenium, testng, dataprovider

I want the actions(switch to frame, NavigateToAgents and writeToExcel) to be performed on multiple instances that open from Webdriver.get(urls). for now it just runs rest of the actions(switch to frame, NavigateToAgents and writeToExcel) on 1st instance of browser that is opened but not on others.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "data")
public static void stopAgents(String urls) throws Exception {

    setup();    //Setup of browser

    WebDriver.get(urls); // opening multiple instances of webdriver from list of urls from dataprovider

    switchToLeftFrame();

    navigateToAgents();

    writeToExcel(sheetName, methodType); //i want to write to excel the tables of both the instances which are opened
```

//dataprovider passes list of urls

```
   @DataProvider(name = "data", parallel = true)
    public Object[][] data() {

    Configuration configuration = Configuration.getConfiguration();

    List<String> urls = configuration.getListOfUrls();

    Object[][] data = new Object[urls.size()][1];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i][0] = urls.get(i);
    }

    return data;
}
```

// TestNG XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd"> 
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="2">
<test thread-count="5" name="Test">
<classes>
  <class name="testng.data.StopAgents"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Error i get when i run above code

```
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'LH7U05CG7370KZ5', ip: '10.195.232.34', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.execute(JsonInput.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.beginObject(JsonInput.java:103)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.MapCoercer.lambda$apply$1(MapCoercer.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.MapCoercer$$Lambda$105/1929913939.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer$$Lambda$109/1456010139.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.maximize(RemoteWebDriver.java:828)
    at testng.data.MethodsProgress.setup(MethodsProgress.java:450)
    at testng.data.parllel.stopAgents(parllel.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:73)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput$$Lambda$93/585885412.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput$VoidCallable.call(JsonInput.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput$VoidCallable.call(JsonInput.java:176)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.execute(JsonInput.java:168)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: try once without parallel = true in data provision, if it works fine then we need to look further.

Comment: I have added the error which i get. i tried removing parallel = test this makes the test to run 1 by 1 but not parallel. please check the error i get above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass **parallel="tests"** in your XML file.

[For reference read this document](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-suites)

Comment: i have updated the question with error i get, have a look.